# Problems with logic in c# script where images are loaded in a grid type look

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, image-gallery

i have an unknown amount of images that im adding to a Grid control with code and im kind of lost in the logic as images are inserted in wrong order. Have a look (Modulus like this because of testing):

```
    grid.Height = this.Height;
    grid.Width = this.Width;
    grid.ShowGridLines = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        RowDefinition rowDef = new RowDefinition();
        rowDef.Height = new GridLength(50);
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef);
        ColumnDefinition colDef = new ColumnDefinition();
        colDef.Width = new GridLength(50);
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef);
    }
    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        y++;
        if (i % 10 == 0)
        {
            x++;
            y = 1;
        }
        Image img = new Image() { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/positive.png",UriKind.Relative)), Width = 50, Height = 50, Margin = new Thickness(2,2,2,2) };
        grid.Children.Add(img);
        Grid.SetRow(img, x);
        Grid.SetColumn(img, y);
    }
```

Result: [image: Grid of images not starting in the first row at the first coloumn]

As you can see the images are starting on a new row every 10 image as the modulus says, but they do not start at the first row in the first coloumn.

What i want to achieve is this: [image: Image of a gallery in a grid view manner]

What am i doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set intitial values as follows should solve your problem.

```
int x = -1;
int y = -1;
```

And inside if you should try

```
if (i % 10 == 0)
        {
            x++;
            y = 0;
        }
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks it makes sence now!

Answer (score 1):

On your first iteration through the loop, i is 0.

```
(0 % 10 == 0) // true
```

So x is incremented by 1 immediately.

Set a breakpoint at the start of your `for` loop and follow the execution. In this case you'd have seen it immediately.